# Explicit type assignment in Koin singleton

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I have a list of objects which are created using reflection in runtime and the types are not known in compile time. How can I define a singleton object in Koin using its class during runtime? Something like this:

```
val configurations: List<Any> = Configuration.scanAllConfigurations()
module { 
    configurations.forEach { single(it::class) { it } }
}
```

But unfortunately we can not explicitly define Class in single{}. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: single { ... } and singleOf() take an instance. So you need to create one through reflection. How to instantiate them depends on the available constructors. My first try would be _it::class.primaryConstructor?.call()_

Comment: @lukas.j
Giving the instance which is constructed using reflection does not work because coin considers Any as the type. This does not work:

val t : Any = T()
single { t }

Answer (score 0):

Using bind can solve the issue:

```
single { it } bind it.javaClass.kotlin
```